# How to link to an external URL stored in a database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a website URL that I saved in a form that stores in the database table as: `www.cnn.com`.

When retrieving the above in a view I have the following code, where I try to link to the external URL `www.cnn.com` that I stored in my table column. It's titled as "Project url":

```
<table class="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Project title </th>
              <th>Project url </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <% @user_portfolio_list.each do |accom| %>
          <tr>

              <td><%=  accom.projecttitle %></td>
              <td><%= link_to accom.projecturl.html_safe, accom.projecturl.html_safe %></td>

              <% #= URI::escape(accom.projecturl.html_safe) %>

          </tr>
          <br>
          <% end %>
          <%= will_paginate @user_portfolio_list %>

       </table>
```

When I go to my browser, I do have the link, but upon following the link I'm led to the following:

```
http://localhost:3001/jobapplications/jobapplistprofile/%3Cp%3Ewww.cnn.com%3C/p%3E
```

How do I link to the stored website address from the view?

Comment: `www.cnn.com` is a hostname and not a valid URL. `https://www.cnn.com` might be a valid URL. Why do you store the hostname without the protocol? To build a valid URL from that hostname you would have to guess the protocol. Prefixing all hostnames with `https://` might be a good guess. It would be better to store the full URL including the protocol in the database in the first place.

Comment: Please take a moment to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting. I've reformatted your post to remove a LOT of unnecessary formatting including fixing the title that was in all caps. You should try comparing your original question to others you see here on SO; flashy formatting is not only unnecessary, it's distracting clutter. We prefer to focus on the content of your question, not its presentation.